# How to automatically clear cache on user's already loaded website whenever a new build is generated?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, react-boilerplate, webpack-config

I am using this react boilerplate code - https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate and webpack - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/
The problem I am facing is whenever I am doing npm run build and pushing the build folder to prod, users have to manually do ctr+shift+r to see the latest changes.
I have tried many methods of hashing script etc, to clear the cache on new build but none is working.
One of the method i tried is - https://dev.to/ammartinwala52/clear-cache-on-build-for-react-apps-1k8j
But the thing is in my build folder there isn't any public folder or any meta.json.
Any help will be appreciated